# microsoft sso is not working in social-auth-app-django=5.4.0 in Django

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, social-auth-app-django

We have used the social-auth-app-django=5.4.0 package for sso both Microsoft and google.
The Google SSo is working properly but Microsoft SSO is not working. It shows the below error while trying to SSO.

````
Backend not found
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:9090/login/microsoft-oauth2/
Raised by:  social_django.views.auth
Using the URLconf defined in jenkins_mail.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

app/
[name='home']
admin/
login/<str:backend>/ [name='begin']
The current path, login/microsoft-oauth2/, matched the last one.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.```
````